# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: getElementsByClassName is not defined

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to append some text data to an Elementor div using fetch and WordPress custom REST API I made. But I'm always getting this error:

Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: getElementsByClassName is not defined

Here is the code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-post__title").length; i++) {
    let fetchRes = fetch("https://localhost/paperclasslk/wp-json/quiz/v1/search?name="+document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-post__title")[i].innerText);
    fetchRes.then(res => res.json()).then(d => { 
        if (d['quiz_max_score'] === null) {
           const para = document.createElement("p");
           para.innerText = "Quiz " + i + " score is: No score";
           document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-post__excerpt")[i].appendChild(para);
        } else {
           const para = document.createElement("p");
           para.innerText = "Quiz " + i + " score is: " + d['quiz_max_score'];
           document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-post__excerpt")[i].appendChild(para);
        }
    })
}
```

Hopefully everyone can help me. Thank you and have a good day!

Comment: Can you provide your HTML code?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the actual error message `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: getElementsByClassName is not defined`?

Comment: @Konrad I'd assume the message is actually `getElementsByClassName[...] is not defined`.

Comment: @Konrad, yes, that's the actual error message.

Comment: @Teemu, the error message in the title and in the description is the actual error message.

Comment: @kimshee16 I can't believe that. You've a typical "past of array" situation here, make it like `for (let i = 0, ...)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1169519